# why am I able to SSH from command line, but not from `datalab connect`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I've been playing with `google datalab` and it's hard to get a connection to the `notebook`

I can create/launch an instance successfuly but usually the `notebook` is unavailable

```
$ datalab create [instance]
Connecting to [instance].

This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Connection broken
Attempting to reconnect...
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
```

however, even while the `notebook` is unavailable, I can always SSH from the console

`gcloud compute --project "[project]" ssh --zone "asia-east1-a" "[instance]"`

sometimes I `^C` and try again with `datalab connect [instance]` and it will eventually work. 
Am I doing anything wrong, or is it just hit/miss?

Comment: Does this only occur after you've run `datalab create`, or can you reproduce by running `datalab connect` on a VM that has been running for some time?

Comment: Is any error being returned or does it just take forever to connect? I have tried myself and it its true that it takes some time (connection after `datalab create` took >5min, but connection with `datalab connect --zone <MY_ZONE> --port 8081 <MY_INSTANCE>` was almost instantaneous. Has this always happened to you or is this a transient issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sometimes takes a few minutes for `datalab` to connect. If it does not connect, I also do as you describe and open a new Cloud Shell window (or use `tmux` to start another "tab") to run `datalab connect [env]` which usually works.

I believe this delay occurs because the web/notebook server takes time to start up after the environment is built.